# Adal.js returns a token with invalid permission with a powerbi resource

Tags: oauth-2.0, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, adal.js

I'm having issue authenticating with Azure Active Directory which is linked to a power BI service.  I'm trying to get an access token so that I can access the power bi rest API.

If i use postman, I'm able to successfully use their OAuth2 login to retrieve a token that has the correct credentials to communicate with the power bi rest API.

However, when I try to do this with the adal.js the token is invalid.  To simplify this to be able to reproduced, I based my project off

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi

You need to update window config in : \active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi\TodoSPA\App\Scripts\app.js

```
  window.config = {
        instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
        tenant: <insert tenant>,
        clientId: <insert clientid>,
        postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage', // enable this for IE, as sessionStorage does not work for localhost.
        endpoints: {
            "https://api.powerbi.com": "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api",

        }
    };
```

**Workaround**
I'm able to get the token via silent authentication where you have to hard code the username and password.

I followed this http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/How-to-use-Power-BI-Rest-API-without-GUI-authentication-redirect/m-p/14218#M119 to create the request for silent authentication:

```
Post Url: https://login.windows.net/<tenant>/oauth2/token

Body:
password: <password>
username: <username>
client_id: <clientid>
client_secret: <secret>
grant_type: password
scope: openId
resource: https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api
```

I also validated that the account I used had the correct permission by using postman and authorization with OAuth2.  The token I received had the correct permission for PowerBI.

**Post Man Configuration**

On postman, click on Authorization Tab -> Set Type to OAuth2.0 -> Get New Access Token:

The configuration you would use:

AuthUrl: https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/authorize?resource=https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api

Access Token URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/token

Grant Type: Authorization Code:

Client ID: 
Client Secret:

Go to https://dev.powerbi.com/apps to generate the clientID/ClientSecret and set the Redirect URL: https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback

postman generated token:

```
{
  "aud": "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/<id>/",
  "iat": 1500464096,
  "nbf": 1500464096,
  "exp": 1500467996,
  "acr": "1",
  "aio": <value>,
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ],
  "appid": <app_id>,
  "appidacr": "1",
  "family_name": "Sunderam",
  "given_name": <userName>,
  "ipaddr": "23.252.49.99",
  "name": <name>,
  "oid": <oid_id>,
  "platf": "3",
  "puid": <puid_id>,
  "scp": "Content.Create Dashboard.Read.All Data.Alter_Any Dataset.Read.All Dataset.ReadWrite.All Group.Read Group.Read.All Metadata.View_Any Report.Read.All Report.ReadWrite.All",
  "sub": <sub_id>,
  "tid": <tid_id>,
  "unique_name": <user_email>,
  "upn": <user_email>,
  "ver": "1.0",
  "wids": [
    <wid_id>
  ]
}
```

adal.js token

```
{
  "aud": <aud_id>,
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/<id>/",
  "iat": 1501037728,
  "nbf": 1501037728,
  "exp": 1501041628,
  "aio": <aio_id>",
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ],
  "family_name": <name>,
  "given_name": <name>,
  "ipaddr": "23.252.49.99",
  "name": ,"name"
  "nonce": "b21969c3-ae73-4928-bcd0-e9c501f791e4",
  "oid": <oid_id>,
  "platf": "5",
  "sub": <sub_id>,
  "tid": <tid_id>,
  "unique_name": <user_email>,
  "upn": <user_email>,
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

Notice that the postman token has the scp, appid, and wids.

Any Advice appreciated,
Thanks,
Derek

Comment: What's the flow to get the token using the postman? And I suggest that you check the request to see whether the token was append correctly. You can also compare the token using by adal.js with getting from postman.

Comment: If they are delegate-token, you can see the `scp` claim in the token.

Comment: @FeiXue I tried to monitor the traffic with fiddler for the adal.js but it wasn't what I expected.  With postman, it went through the whole OAuth2 with the trigger to get the code and then the redirect to the assigned url.  When that request to get the access_token.  However, with the adal.js I don't see the two url calls to get the code, the call back and then the request to get the token.  I have compared the tokens and they are different.

Comment: @FeiXue Added configuration for postman.  Also the reason why i know that the token was appended correctly to the request is because I just replaced the token with the one that I got from postman with the one i got from adal.js.  It would work for one and not the other.  Also the tokens are different.  So there is something i'm not understanding with the adal.js.  I'm assuming that you have to request certain resource which I thought i was doing correctly with the adal.js library. But I could be doing it wrong.

Comment: The adal.js is using the implicit flow to acquire the token using the hiding iframe. So would you mind share claims in the two token? You can decode it from [this site](https://jwt.io/).

Comment: @FeiXue so it seems that I'm probably comparing oranges to apples.  Where postman does an client credential grant vs. adal.js does an implicit auth flow.  So i'm still a little confused on how to get the implicit flow to work correctly with adal.js

Comment: In you original post, you were acquire the toke using **Authorization code grant flow** via post man. And now you mentioned you used the **Client Credentials Flow**.  And based on the token claims, you should use the delegate-token. Adal.js token looks incorrect since there is no `scp` claim. Did you get the token from the request or only get the token from local storage?

Comment: For the adal.js, first you login-in the Azure ad after that when you send the request to the PowerBI, it will automatically to check whether the token exits in the cache, if not it will create a hide iframe and get the token with implicit flow and since the Azure AD already sign-in it will get the token silently.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize that adal.js was a different flow.  From local storage.  The id-token is set to the same as the access token.  This is configured by adal.js when i try to authenticate.login which seems incorrect.  I'm confused at why access_token is even set if it could mean something else.  What is the delegate-token?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150142/discussion-between-darewreck-and-fei-xue).

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the token via the request. For example, you can check it via the developer tools-Network tab(Chrome, F12).

And based on the token and code, the config seems incorrect. For the `endpoints` is the collection of **{Endpoint-ResourceId}** used for automatically attaching tokens in webApi calls.

You can use the config like below:

```
 window.config = {
        instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
        tenant: <insert tenant>,
        clientId: <insert clientid>,
        postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage', // enable this for IE, as sessionStorage does not work for localhost.
        endpoints: {
            "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api": "https://api.powerbi.com",

        }
    };
```

More detail about this library, you can refer this [link](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js).

Comment: thanks, i'll take a look and try it out.  the documentation refers to a usage with the angular library.  I'm using a react application so only can use adal.js